# Extract rows from table where values are less than and greater than in columns in shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a very large tab separated table (24 gb in size) with `C1` and `C2` , `C3` and `C4` columns as shown below. I would like to extract rows that have C1 < 0.6 and C2 < 0.4. How do I do in unix/ shell using logical operators?

```
C1     C2    C3     C4
0.8    0.1   A1     C.a 
0.2    0.3   A2     C.b
0.5    0.8   A3     C.c
0.1    0.1   A4     C.c
```

Result I expect:

```
C1     C2    C3     C4
0.2    0.3   A2     C.b
0.1    0.1   A4     C.c
```

Comment: Could you please do let me know if my answer helped you here?

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** This simple `awk` should do the job for you.

```
awk 'FNR==1 || ($1<.6 && $2<.4)' Input_file
```

OR for tab separated Input_file try following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}FNR==1 || ($1<.6 && $2<.4)' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution(Generic one):*** In case you don't want to hard code field number of field `c1` and `c2` and want to get it programmatically then try following. Add `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` in following in case your Input_file is TAB delimited.

```
awk -v c1Thre="0.6" -v c2Thre="0.4" '
FNR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i=="C1"){ C1Field=i }
    if($i=="C2"){ C2Field=i }
  }
  print
  next
}
$C1Field<c1Thre && $C2Field<c2Thre
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Bit shorter: `awk -F '\t' 'NR==1 || ($1<.6 && $2<.4)' file`

Comment: @anubhava, Thank you sir edited the solution now, keeping 2 solutions 1 when Input_file is NOT `\t` separated and another when Input_file is tab separated here.

Answer (score 0):

try this :
I have removed spaces ( there are 3/4 spaces ) and changed them to "," for processing :

```
cat mydata.txt | tr -s " " "," | awk -F"," 'BEGIN { X = NF } { for (i = 0; i <= X; i = i + 1) if($1 < 0.6 && $2<0.4) print $0}'
```

Comment: @JamesBrown : Ya I was checking on the data he pasted , so have to make it consistent , thanks.